# 'iterator' object has no attribute 'next' in python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, iterator, pytorch

I'm trying to iterate through my data set and get the first element

```
    transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(),transforms.Normalize((0.5),(0.5)),])
    trainloader = datasets.MNIST('~/.pytorch/MNIST_data' , download=True,train=True , transform=transform)
    ds = iter(trainloader)
    img, labels = ds.next()
```

but it returns this error

```
    AttributeError: 'iterator' object has no attribute 'next'
```

I also tried this

```
    img , labels = next(ds)
```

returned this error

```
    StopIteration:
```

Did I miss something ?

Comment: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torchvision/datasets/mnist.html MNIST class implements __getitem__. So why not just use `trainloader[0]` to get the first item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you follow the tutorial on https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html

```
trainset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=True,
                                        download=True, transform=transform)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=4,
                                          shuffle=True, num_workers=2)

dataiter = iter(trainloader)
images, labels = dataiter.next()
```

You are missing the DataLoader() function on your dataset

Answer (score 4):

Might be this issue:
https://github.com/microsoft/DeepSpeedExamples/issues/222

Then change from:

```
images, labels = dataiter.next()
```

to:

```
images, labels = next(dataiter)
```